# SVG symbol with stroke has wrong size in Illustrator

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

I'm generating an SVG file on a website and it's supposed to be imported in Ilustrator. I use `<symbol />` element to store a shape definition and I reference it with the `<use />` element on the "sheet". Users are able to set size of the shape and it's really crucial that it's exactly the same size when imported to Adobe Illustrator. It works unless I add a stroke.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg id="SvgjsSvg1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" width="210mm" height="297mm" viewBox="0 0 210 297" viewbox="0 0 210 297">
    <defs id="SvgjsDefs1001">
        <symbol id="shape_id70" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 27.841039657592773 12.2083101272583">
            <path id="SvgjsPath1030" d="M26.4405 13.067C25.685728 11.72066 22.49458 8.90142 20.73442 7.678030000000001C22.99088 7.6388854 23.85819 7.6146637 28.738950000000003 7.456081C26.298620000000003 6.628644 23.737080000000002 5.904501 21.418080000000003 4.973881C23.937200000000004 4.5081560000000005 26.519460000000002 4.085806000000001 28.376120000000004 3.7947010000000008C28.376120000000004 3.7946453179000006 19.370760000000004 2.7013810000000005 8.358420000000002 4.414499000000001L9.412540000000002 1.364679000000001L6.497860000000001 3.520859000000001L4.442800000000001 0.858699000000001L4.324531000000001 4.464059000000001L0.897911000000001 5.542179000000001L4.249861000000001 6.913239000000001L4.236664300000001 10.198599000000002L6.192894300000001 7.622079000000001L9.099554300000001 8.802649L8.143547300000002 6.432539C12.463087300000002 6.813516 22.5756473 8.818239 26.440547300000002 13.067009Z" fill="none"></path>
        </symbol>
    </defs>
    <use id="SvgjsUse1034" xlink:href="#shape_id70" x="0" y="0" width="50"></use>
</svg>
```

This is fine in both browser and Illustrator. But when I add attributes `stroke-width="0.1" stroke="#000"`. In Illustrator, the size of the shape changesto 48.951. It's still 50 in browser though. I tried to add these attributes to the `<symbol />`, `<path />` and `<use />` elements with the same result.

I know that the SVG standard doesn't have any attribute that would control how to render the stroke. I know there is a discussion about the stroke-alignment attribute for future versions of SVG. But browsers don't support that yet, and neither Adobe Illustrator.

So my question is: Is there any way how to adjust the SVG so that Illustrator would render the shape with the size that is set by the width attribute in the `<use />` element regardless of the stroke settings

Comment: If you think you've found a bug in inkscape best report it to [its bugtracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape)

Answer (score 0):

The `width` value on your `<use>` should be having no effect on your `<symbol>` because your symbol has no `viewBox` attribute.  Without a viewBox, only the `x` and `y` attributes of the `<use>` will be doing anything.

Also, be aware that we've seen a few questions on S.O. in the past, complaining about bugs in Illustrator's SVG import filter.  If `<symbol>` is working, then that's great.  However, in general, you may find that keeping your SVG structure simple, and avoiding the more advanced SVG features, might be a good idea.

Comment: I'm sorry. While simplifying the source I deleted too much. I edited my question and added the viewBox attribute. It was just a mistake. I know that when I have a shape in definition (let's say in a group, not symbol) I can also use reference (<use />). But in that case I need to resize the definition and that's what I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Then, if that's the case, it definitely sounds like a bug in Illustrator.  You might try reporting it to them.

Comment: In the meantime, you may have to use the alternative you suggested, a group. You don't have to resize the definition. You can always just use a `transform` on the `<use>` element.  https://jsfiddle.net/gwauq55x/